# Search content from a file dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have file (dictionary) and I want to search a specific content from a file, how to write the query?

```
def name_search():
    target = open("customers.txt",'r')
    name_search = input('Search >')
    for line in target:
        if name_search in line:
            print(f'{name_search} in record!')
        else:
            print('Not in record!')
```

The above code works, however, it tries to print this line multiple times depending how many lines I have in file. Assuming the line is not present:

```
Not in record!
Not in record!
Not in record!
Not in record!
```

Comment: Are you saying you only want to print something once? It isn't clear what the desired behavior is from your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying you do not want to print multiple times, only once at the end of reading the whole file, then do something like this:

```
def name_search():
    target = open("customers.txt",'r')
    name_search = input('Search >')
    found = False  # use this to remember if we found something
    for line in target:
        if name_search in line:
            print(f'{name_search} in record!')
            found = True  # remember we found it!
            break  # this kicks you out of the loop, so you stop searching after you find something
    if not found:
        print('Not in record!')  # only prints this if we didn't find anything
```

Alternatively, and in fewer lines of code, you can use a `return` statement in the "found" case. There are reasons people like to avoid having multiple return points in their code, but I present it here as an option:

```
def name_search():
    target = open("customers.txt",'r')
    name_search = input('Search >')
    for line in target:
        if name_search in line:
            print(f'{name_search} in record!')
            return  # kicks us out of the function after we find something
    print('Not in record!')  # still only prints this if we didn't find anything
```